# Why is Cronjob running at wrong time

Tags: linux

I am very much new to Linux , so please excuse if this is a dumb question

This is the way i have set up my cronjob to daily run at  **5:10 PM**

and this is the way i have set it up in crontab editor

```
10 17 * * * /opt/customdir/dailynse.sh
```

I checked in the crontab logs for this job using

```
grep -i daily /var/log/cron
```

I found below line

**Jan 12 17:10:01 s97-74-xxx-xxx CROND[15736]: (root) CMD (/opt/customdir/dailynse.sh)**

and this is date in my machine

```
root@s97-74-xxx-xxx [/opt/customdir]# date
Wed Jan 13 18:03:35 IST 2016
```

I found only one instance and this is the output of it 
Could you please tell me why it showing Jan 12 rather than Jan 13 ??

Please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: What is the time zone that cron is using?

Comment: could you please tell me how can i check that ??

Comment: Get current time. Add entry to crontab `<X> * * * * date > /tmp/date.text` - Where X is the number of minutes past the hour in a minute or two ahead. Wait. Read the file `/tmp/date.txt`. Remove the crontab entry when done. File will give you the time zone